# Nexus 5 Calendar event added as birthday while inserting programmatically

Tags: android

In nexus 5 , i added event to calendar programmatically  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tW50g.png).But event adding as a birthday. can any one please help me out?

```
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
    contentValues.put(Events.TITLE, event.getTitle());
    contentValues.put(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, event.getAddress());
    contentValues.put(Events.DTSTART, calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    contentValues.put(Events.DTEND, calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    contentValues.put(Events.ALL_DAY, 0);   // 0 for false, 1 for true
    contentValues.put(Events.HAS_ALARM, 0); // 0 for false, 1 for true
    String timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
    contentValues.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone);
    getContentResolver().insert(baseUri, contentValues);
```

Comment: What do you mean by `content value(6.0)` ?

Comment: sorry, using  this getContentResolver().insert(baseUri, contentValues);(in marshmallow)

Comment: We have the same problem, any idea?

Comment: Even we are facing this same issue.

Comment: Apparently it seems to be a problem with google calendar update. Uninstall the calendar update and try. It started working for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: Same problem. But works after uninstalling the update and even after re-updating the Calendar App.